# Prevent Kubernetes users from being able to create privileged containers

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently attempting to look into whether it's possible to prevent a Kubernetes user from creating privileged containers via RBAC. I'm aware that as of Kubernetes 1.1, privileged containers are enabled by default to support underlying Docker requirements. This is fine, I'm not looking to block *everybody* from being able to run privileged containers.

I would, however, like to work on a principle of least privilege. For example, I'd like to prevent users being able to use something such as [kubectl node-shell](https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-node-shell) from being able to gain root access to a worker node, preferably through RBAC.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this and I'd like to start with the first, official one: [Pod Security Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/).

The policy you want to implement is the following: [Privileged](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged)

> determines if any container in a pod can enable privileged mode. By default a container is not allowed to access any devices on the host, but a "privileged" container is given access to all devices on the host. This allows the container nearly all the same access as processes running on the host. This is useful for containers that want to use linux capabilities like manipulating the network stack and accessing devices.

The Kubernetes documentation provides few examples on how to interact with PSP, although a big disclaimer must be stated: the [PodSecurityPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podsecuritypolicy) admission controlled must be activated on the API Server.

Besides the official admission controller, there are other projects that allow performing the denial of containers matching criteria, as well as running as privileged: [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper), [Kyverno](https://github.com/kyverno/kyverno).

There are other projects that can address your use-case but wanted to share these last two since they seem the most promising ones.

#### Examples

- [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/tree/master/library/pod-security-policy/privileged-containers)
- [Kyverno](https://github.com/kyverno/kyverno/blob/main/samples/DisallowPrivilegedContainers.md)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Once [PodSecurityPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podsecuritypolicy) have been enabled on you cluster, the [standard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-standards/#policy-instantiation) recommends creating 3 levels of policies:

- privileged
- baseline
- restricted
  then you have to use RBAC to map these policies with your users. Here is a minimalist example for all of these: https://github.com/k8s-school/kind-travis-ci/tree/master/psp. It will at least allow to boostrap the control plane once PodSecurityPolicies are enabled, indeed kube-proxy and CNI daemonset, and coredns deployment service accounts require some rights on PodSecurityPolicies in order to be able to create their related pod.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer as of 1.23 is to use Pod Security Standards that are enforced by the Pod Security Admission controller which is included by default since 1.23. K8s has removed Pod Security Policy (PSP) in 1.25 an PSP was deprecated in 1.23.

K8s comes with 3 pre-defined Pod Security Standards: Privileged, Baseline and Restricted. Enforcing the Baseline and Restricted standards would both allow you to prevent privileged pods. However, restricted might be too restrictive for your pod so I would recommend starting with the baseline standard.

### Enforcing the baseline Pod Security Standard

Enforcing a pod security standard to a namespace has the risk of preventing new pods from being deployed to the namespace. So lets do a dry-run first instead of directly enforcing baseline.

Run a dry-run and check if any warnings are thrown:

```bash
kubectl label --dry-run=server --overwrite ns default \
    pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce=baseline
```

If you saw namespace/default labeled without any warnings then that means all the currently running pods inside the namespace default would have been admitted if baseline was enforced.

Assuming you had no warnings. Let's start by enforcing the baseline standard on the default namespace:

```bash
kubectl label --overwrite ns default \
    pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce=baseline
```

Notice that this time the --dry-run=server parameter is not added.

Let's verify that privileged pods indeed are getting blocked.

Create a file named nginx-priv.yaml with the following content:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-priv
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-priv
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Try to create the privileged pod:

```bash
kubectl apply -f nginx-priv.yaml
```

You should see the following output:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "nginx-priv.yaml": pods "nginx-priv" is forbidden: violates PodSecurity "baseline:latest": privileged (container "nginx-priv" must not set securityContext.privileged=true)
```

Note you can also enforce baseline across all namespaces like this (might cause issues when deploying new pods):

```bash
kubectl label --overwrite ns --all \
  pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce=baseline
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of below source
Source: https://samos-it.com/posts/Preventing-Privileged-pods-using-Pod-Security-Admission-Standards.html